# App works on simulator but doesn't work on iPhone (swift 2 and xcode 7)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, swift2, xcode7

I made app in swift 2 and xcode 7. It works on the simulator but does not work on an iPhone 6. Why is it?

It crashes when the TabBar is clicked and then a chat message is tapped

I use this library:

https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

for the chat messages

**Error log:**

```
 Kamol, [02.12.15 14:49]
{"app_name":"maktub","app_version":"1.0","bundleID":"uz.futuresoft.maktub","adam_id":0,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.4 (12H143)","slice_uuid":"cbddcfc8-7bbb-3765-805c-b7352bc5245d","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"1","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"maktub"}
Incident Identifier: EF19A878-B639-47BE-B3C0-376AE5892DAD
CrashReporter Key: d9dae756a92cb540dd6c07d93162d74b72d2109d
Hardware Model: iPhone7,2
Process: maktub [1093]
Path: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/242B74B9-9368-4639-B939-FF1624D7AD7C/maktub.app/maktub
Identifier: uz.futuresoft.maktub
Version: 1 (1.0)
Code Type: ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [1]

Date/Time: 2015-12-02 14:10:10.356 +0500
Launch Time: 2015-12-02 14:09:50.479 +0500
OS Version: iOS 8.4 (12H143)
Report Version: 105

Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100061844
Triggered by Thread: 0

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 maktub 0x0000000100061844 0x100010000 + 333892
1 maktub 0x0000000100087fc0 0x100010000 + 491456
2 maktub 0x00000001000882d0 0x100010000 + 492240
3 UIKit 0x0000000188334c14 0x188324000 + 68628
4 UIKit 0x0000000188334924 0x188324000 + 67876
5 UIKit 0x00000001884d71ec 0x188324000 + 1782252
6 UIKit 0x00000001883e9e80 0x188324000 + 810624
7 UIKit 0x00000001883e9c4c 0x188324000 + 810060
8 UIKit 0x00000001883e9bcc 0x188324000 + 809932
9 UIKit 0x00000001883316f0 0x188324000 + 55024
10 QuartzCore 0x0000000187c6ddb4 0x187c60000 + 56756
11 QuartzCore 0x0000000187c6881c 0x187c60000 + 34844
12 QuartzCore 0x0000000187c686c0 0x187c60000 + 34496
13 QuartzCore 0x0000000187c67e54 0x187c60000 + 32340
14 QuartzCore 0x0000000187c67bd4 0x187c60000 + 31700
15 QuartzCore 0x0000000187c612fc 0x187c60000 + 4860
16 CoreFoundation 0x00000001838742a0 0x183794000 + 918176
17 CoreFoundation 0x000000018387122c 0x183794000 + 905772
18 CoreFoundation 0x000000018387160c 0x183794000 + 906764
19 CoreFoundation 0x000000018379d2d0 0x183794000 + 37584
20 GraphicsServices 0x000000018d1f36f8 0x18d1e8000 + 46840
21 UIKit 0x000000018839af3c 0x188324000 + 487228
22 maktub 0x000000010007ebd0 0x100010000 + 453584
23 libdyld.dylib 0x0000000195c32a04 0x195c30000 + 10756

Thread 1 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000195d30c24 0x195d30000 + 3108
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000195c15e6c 0x195c04000 + 73324
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000195c07998 0x195c04000 + 14744

Thread 2:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000195d4bc78 0x195d30000 + 113784
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000195de52d8 0x195de4000 + 4824
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000195de4eec 0x195de4000 + 3820

Thread 3:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000195d4bc78 0x195d30000 + 113784
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000195de52d8 0x195de4000 + 4824
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000195de4eec 0x195de4000 + 3820

Thread 4:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000195d4bc78 0x195d30000 + 113784
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000195de52d8 0x195de4000 + 4824
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000195de4eec 0x195de4000 + 3820

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
 x0: 0x0000000000000001 x1: 0x00000001000007f0 x2: 0x0000000174245fd8 x3: 0x000000016fdecce6
 x4: 0x0000000000000400 x5: 0x000000016fdec980 x6: 0x000000000

Kamol, [02.12.15 14:49]
0000001 x7: 0x0000000000000002
 x8: 0x0000000000000000 x9: 0x000001a596256959 x10: 0x0000000000000007 x11: 0x0000000196263120
 x12: 0x000000013e827cc0 x13: 0x000001a596256959 x14: 0x006d00750063006f x15: 0x00730074006e0065
 x16: 0x0000000195ddd698 x17: 0x00000001837bdbac x18: 0x0000000000000000 x19: 0x0000000000000000
 x20: 0x0000000170474900 x21: 0x0000000174245fd0 x22: 0x0000000000000000 x23: 0x0000000174245fd0
 x24: 0xc000000000000070 x25: 0x00000001001cb000 x26: 0x0000000174170200 x27: 0x00000001001cc000
 x28: 0x00000001001cc000 fp: 0x000000016fded210 lr: 0x00000001000617c0
 sp: 0x000000016fded1a0 pc: 0x0000000100061844 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Do you have some advices? Thanks

Comment: Symbolicate the crash log. Otherwise it's useless.

Comment: Install crashlytics. Its free and it will inform the exact line where your app is crashed. https://try.crashlytics.com